# Python. Сохранение списка в другую переменную

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код:

```
a = [5, 3, 8]
b = a
b.pop(1)
print(a, b)
```

Вот вывод:

```
[5, 8] [5, 8]
```

Вопрос. Почему я выкидывая второе значение из списка "b" так же выкинул это значение и из списка "a"?? 
"b = a" означает, что все значения всегда будут идентичны у этих листов? 
Как мне тогда сделать "бекап" листа в другой переменной?

Comment: Потому что переменная `B` будет хранить ссылку на список `A`, а не копию списка.. А чтобы использовать копию то для этого есть метод `copy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте срез списка по всей длине

```
a = [5, 3, 8]
b = a[:]
b.pop(1)
print(a, b)
```

или `b = a.copy()`

Comment: Или `b = list(a)`.